# How to pass null values for Password in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I don't want to show password while edit profile. I am using below syntax for password

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'password',['template' => "{input}"])->passwordInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>
```

How can i pass null values for password ?

Comment: Are you looking for these kind of things.https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-models.md#fields-

Comment: No, I need like this <input type="password" name="password" value="" />

Comment: Then try it with afterFind(), Model property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'password',['template' => "{input}"])->passwordInput(['maxlength' => 255,'value'=>'']) ?>
```

Key note is `'value'=>''`

However, it is suggested to do like below in your controller:

```
$model->password=NULL;
```

Or

```
$model->password="";
```

Then, render your view.

Comment: Thanks #Ali MasudianPour.