# create and update user from active record

Tags: activerecord, save, yii2, overwrite

i did CRUD in backend on user table in class extend ActiveRecord. But in my table i have a lot of data which i dont want to give the user to fill for example auth_assignment, createdAt. So i dont know now how i can use function which fill it for user. I know that in SignupForm for example i can use method save() and there i can use function generate auth_key for example. In model i often use this function:

```
public function saveProfile() {

        $model = $this->_user;
        $model->Name=$this->Name;
        $model->Surname=$this->Surname;
        $model->Login=$this->Login;
        $model->Rel_Sex= $this->Sex;
        $model->setAttributes($this->getAttributes());
        $model->BirthDate = $this->getDbFormatedDate();
        $model->Rel_Country = $this->Country;
        $model->Rel_Language = $this->Language;
        $model->Email = $this->Email;
        $model->Rel_UserCategory= $this->Category;
        $model->setPassword($this->Password);

       if ($this->validate() && $model->validate()) {
            $model->save();
            return $model;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But i dont know how to overwirte method save() in ActiveRecord. So i have this class extend ActiveRecord:

```
<?php

namespace backend\modules\users\models;

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;


class Uruser extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'uruser';
    }



    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['Name', 'Surname', 'BirthDate', 'Login', 'Email', 'PasswordHash', 'created_at', 'Rel_Sex', 'auth_key', 'status', 'auth_assignment'], 'required'],
            [['BirthDate'], 'safe'],
            [['RulesAccept', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'Rel_Sex', 'Rel_Country', 'Rel_Language', 'Rel_UserCategory', 'Rel_AccountType', 'Rel_RoyalUserData', 'Rel_EmailPermission', 'Rel_CommercialPermission', 'IsDeleted', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['Name', 'Surname', 'Login', 'Email', 'PasswordResetToken', 'auth_key', 'auth_assignment'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['PasswordHash'], 'string', 'max' => 90]
        ];
    }
```

And i fill only email, birthdate, login, name. But i want to use some function to fill my attributes on save. For example generate AuthKey.

```
 public function setPassword($password)
    {
       return $this->PasswordHash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
       return $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }
```

How i can do this on save?

When i used beforeSave it not work:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if($this->isNewRecord) {
                $this->generateAuthKey();
                $this->setPassword($this->PasswordHash);
                $this->status=1;
                $this->created_at=date('Y-m-d');
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I var_dum in controller:

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Uruser();

        var_dump($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()), $model->save(),$model->getErrors());
        exit();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

An i have this:

> bool(true) bool(false) array(3) { ["created_at"]=> array(1) { [0]=>
>   string(27) "Created At cannot be blank." } ["auth_key"]=> array(1) {
>   [0]=> string(25) "Auth Key cannot be blank." } ["status"]=> array(1) {
>   [0]=> string(23) "Status cannot be blank." } }

When i used beforeSave now when i update password then it not hashed my password and sawe this waht i wrote. I try this in my Model but it isnt work:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if($this->isNewRecord) {
                $this->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $this->status = self::DEFAULT_STATUS;
                $this->generateAuthKey();
                $this->setPassword($this->PasswordHash);
                $this->RulesAccept=1;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->setPassword($this->PasswordHash);
            $this->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            return true;
        }
    }
```

AFTER EDIT

```
 public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if($this->isNewRecord) {
                $this->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $this->status = self::DEFAULT_STATUS;
                $this->generateAuthKey();
                $this->setPassword($this->PasswordHash);
                $this->RulesAccept=1;
                return true;
            }
            else {
            $this->setPassword($this->PasswordHash);
            $this->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            return true;
        }
        } 
    }
```

this work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the beforeSave method in your model. This method is called at the beginning of inserting or updating a record. If you want to save the new attributes only when you insert a new record you should use the isNewRecord property.

```
class Uruser extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['Name', 'Surname', 'BirthDate', 'Login', 'Email', 'PasswordHash', 'Rel_Sex', 'auth_assignment'], 'required'],
            [['BirthDate'], 'safe'],
            [['RulesAccept', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'Rel_Sex', 'Rel_Country', 'Rel_Language', 'Rel_UserCategory', 'Rel_AccountType', 'Rel_RoyalUserData', 'Rel_EmailPermission', 'Rel_CommercialPermission', 'IsDeleted', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['Name', 'Surname', 'Login', 'Email', 'PasswordResetToken', 'auth_key', 'auth_assignment'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['PasswordHash'], 'string', 'max' => 90]
        ];
    }
    ....
    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if($this->isNewRecord) {
                $this->created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $this->status = self::DEFAULT_STATUS;
                $this->generateAuthKey();
                $this->setPassword($this->password);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

More information [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeSave()-detail).

Comment: thanks for answer but it not work i dont know why i update my first post look at this if u have time

Comment: sorry. i didn't notice the required rules. you've got this errors because the created_at, the auth_key and the status fields set as a required fields in the rules method. if you delete these fields (created_at, auth_key, status) in the required part in the rules method and set these fields in the beforeSave method it will be work. I've updated my answer.

Comment: But i have one more question what to do with this passwordhash it hash password given by the user and when i click update it displays me hashed password a lot of dots do not even know how it should look like, and what can i do with this problem

Comment: look at this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601457/how-to-pass-null-values-for-password-in-yii2). it should help. you set an empty value in the password field. when you update fields in the user profile, you should check the password property. if it isn't empty, you create the password hash.

Comment: ok but when i update password there not hased it and in database save me exactly what I wrote and not hashed it

Comment: I should define this in else case in my function before save or in other place? When u pdate always save me letters not hash

Comment: Your beforeSave method is wrong, because the else condition should always return false. I find an article which describes working with profile and password - [link](http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/71/seo-service-on-yii2-user-profile). but it is the russian article. but the article has a good example of password change (look at `class PasswordChangeForm` and  `class ProfileController` there). i hope this example will help you better understand working with the password.

Comment: I editet my first post and show You my beforeSave and it work for me but i have true in else what you think about this

Comment: now your beforeSave is right. but perhaps you will have some problems when you update any properties without the password properties in the user model in other actions. i think password will be changed even if you don't want to change it. i recommend you to look at other examples with change the password (for example here - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced) or look at the russian article -http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/71/seo-service-on-yii2-user-profile. you could improve your code.